# Correct join syntax within multiple queries and sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that end up having the same format. Each has a Month, a year, and some relevant data per month/year. The schema looks like this:

```
subs    Month   Year
8150    1      2015
11060   1      2016
5       2      2014
6962    2      2015
8736    2      2016

Cans    months  years
2984    1       2015
2724    1       2016
13      2       2014
2563    2       2015
1901    2       2016
```

The first query syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(personID) AS subs_per_month,
    MONTH(Date_1) AS month_1,
    YEAR(Date_1) AS year_1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        personID, MIN(date) AS Date_1
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        isSubscription = 1
    GROUP BY personID
    ORDER BY Date_1) AS my_sub_q
GROUP BY month_1 , year_1
```

The second query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ID), MONTH(date) AS months, YEAR(date) AS years
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status = 4 AND isSubscription = 1
GROUP BY months , years
ORDER BY months, years
```

The end goal is to write a simple join so that the final dataset looks like this:

```
subs    cans months years
8150    2984    1   2015
11060   2724    1   2016
5         13    2   2014
6962    2563    2   2015
8736    1901    2   2016
```

I'm a little overwhelmed with how to do this correctly, and after a lot of trial and all error, I thought I'd ask for help. What's confusing is where the `JOIN` goes, and how that looks relative to the rest of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving consideration to simplifying your queries you can use your two queries as inline views and simply select from both (I aliased Q1 and Q2 for your queries and named fields the same within each for simplicity.

```
Select Q1.cnt as Subs, Q2.cnt as Cans, Q1.months, Q1.years
from (SELECT 
    COUNT(personID) AS Cnt,
    MONTH(Date_1) as Months,
    YEAR(Date_1) AS years
    FROM  (SELECT personID, MIN(date) AS Date_1
           FROM orders
           WHERE isSubscription = 1
           GROUP BY personID) AS my_sub_q
    GROUP BY month_1 , year_1) Q1
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ID) cnt, MONTH(date) AS months, YEAR(date) AS years
            FROM orders
            WHERE status = 4 
              AND isSubscription = 1
            GROUP BY months, years) Q2

  ON Q1.Months = Q2.Months
 and Q1.Years = Q2.years
Order by Q1.years, Q2.months
```

Comment: Please, check alias Q1. Seems to be duplicated.

Comment: xQbert, Thanks so much. There were some commas missing and wrong names in there, but the idea was absolutely spot on and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Adrián Thank you. I've updated the second Q1 to Q2 as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary table approach:

```
create temporary table first_query
<<your first query here>>;

create temporary table second_query
<<your second query here>>;

select fq.subs, sq.cans, fq.months, fq.years
from first_query fq
join second_query sq using (months, years)
```

Your table preview and query columns do not match for first query, so I assumed both tables have columns - months and years.

One messy query approach:

```
SELECT fq.subs_per_month subs, sq.cans, sq.months, sq.years
FROM
(SELECT 
    COUNT(personID) AS subs_per_month,
    MONTH(Date_1) AS month_1,
    YEAR(Date_1) AS year_1
FROM
    (SELECT 
    personID, MIN(date) AS Date_1
    FROM
    orders
    WHERE
    isSubscription = 1
    GROUP BY personID
    ORDER BY Date_1) AS my_sub_q
GROUP BY month_1 , year_1) fq
JOIN
(SELECT 
    COUNT(ID) cans, MONTH(date) AS months, YEAR(date) AS years   -- I added 'cans'
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status = 4 AND isSubscription = 1
GROUP BY months , years
ORDER BY months, years) sq
ON fq.month_1 = sq.months AND fq.year_1 = sq.years
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following query

```
select t1.subs as subs,t2.Cans as cans,t1.months,t1.year as years from table1 t1 inner join
table2 t2 on t1.month=t2.months and t1.year=t2.years
```